# header Location is going back to the same POST URL it came from

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

For some reason, my `header("Location: <url>")` is getting redirected to the same POST url it came from. I had to switch to echo a javascript redirect to make it work for the time-being.

```php
catch (Exception $e)
{            
    switch (get_class($e))
    {
        case 'ValidationError':
            $_SESSION['FLASH_ERROR'] = $e->getMessage();
            $location = CB_ABS_URI."upgrade?ID=".$_GET['ID']."&package=".$_POST['plan'];
            # die("You're getting redirected ... <script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout('redirect()',0); function redirect() { window.location = '$location'; }</script>");
            header("Location:", $location);
            exit;
        break;
        default:
            # die
        break;
    }            
}
```

Comment: what is `CB_ABS_URI` constanr?  do you mean it is not redireting to `$location`?

Comment: Its just ABS_URI defined in config. I am switching to Laravel for new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a typo.

```
header("Location:", $location);
```

Should be

```
header("Location: ". $location);
```

You had a comma in the header function.
If you add a comma in the header function your setting the replace parameter in that function as mentioned on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Typos aren't normally answered, especially as your solution has a typo - a missing `.`.

Comment: @NigelRen Where do I miss a `.` then? There is no dot needed in the header function

Comment: `"Location: " $location` - if you want to add the two strings together, you need a `.`

Comment: @NigelRen you're right. Its a good thing we use IDE when we work.

Comment: I forgot that this was a single string - it wasn't a typo - somehow I thought header was taking 2 args. SublimeText or MAMP PRO didnt complain - hence I didnt check the header syntax.

Comment: @anjanesh Don't forget to [read the docs](https://php.net/header)

Comment: Yes - its been while using raw PHP - now into django and laravel.